There is no difference in search speed between CPU and GPU on a million-level dataset
Background
I have one million data, the vector dimension is 1536, and I hope to use GPU to speed up vector query and search
Resource Information

CPU

Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 57 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          104
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-103
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              26
Socket(s):                       2
NUMA node(s):                    2
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           106
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5320 CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:                        6
CPU MHz:                         2800.167
BogoMIPS:                        4400.00
Virtualization:                  VT-x


GPU

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 555.42.02              Driver Version: 555.42.02      CUDA Version: 12.5     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off |   00000000:17:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0             64W /  300W |       1MiB /  81920MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A100 80GB PCIe          Off |   00000000:CA:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0             69W /  300W |       1MiB /  81920MiB |      3%      Default |
|                                         |                        |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+

My steps

Start CPU service: Refer to this link on the official website Run Milvus in Docker
Start GPU service: Refer to this link on the official website Run Milvus with GPU Support Using Docker Compose
Insert data: Use the sample code given on the official website hello_milvus.py, I made some changes:

Data: Change the data volume to 1 million and the data dimension to 1536
Index: CPU version uses IVF_FLAT, nlist is set to 2048, GPU version uses GPU_IVF_FLAT, nlist is set to2048


Search Data: I use the code like:

from pymilvus import MilvusClient, DataType
import time
import numpy as np
import string
import random

milvus_uri = ""
collection_name = ""
client = MilvusClient(uri=milvus_uri)
client.load_collection(collection_name)

search_params = {
   "metric_type": "L2",
   "params": {"nprobe": 32},
}
vectors_to_search = [np.random.rand(1536).tolist() ]
start_time = time.time()
result = client.search(
       collection_name=collection_name,
       data=vectors_to_search, 
       filter = filter_expr,
       anns_field="embeddings", 
       search_params=search_params, 
       limit=10, 
       output_fields=["random"],
       consistency_level="Eventually"
   )
end_time = time.time()
print(f"time cost {end_time-start_time}")


Test time on CPU and GPU services separately. Here are my test results:

To achieve concurrent operation, multiple processes are started at the same time to perform search requests.



GPU IVF FLAT: nprobe: 32



Concurrency
QPS




1
681


5
594


10
546



CPU IVF FLAT: nprobe: 32



Concurrency
QPS




1
680


5
609


10
580



My question:
Why does the GPU not have an acceleration effect? ​​Please help me see if there is anything wrong with the above operation.

Have you verified that the GPU gets used in the second case but not in the first case?

repeated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79046424/why-is-gpu-not-accelerating-vector-search-in-milvus-compared-to-cpu

For CPU index, the time cost of a search request includes the following:

network transfer for the request
ANN computation
network transfer for the result

For GPU index, the time cost of a search request includes the following:

network transfer for the request
target vector copied from CPU memory to GPU memory
ANN computation
result copied from GPU memory to CPU memory
network transfer for the result

We can see there are extra time costs for copying data between CPU memory and GPU memory.
The advantage of GPU search is large NQ search because GPU has strong parallel computing ability.
For small datasets and small NQ searches, it is no much difference between CPU index and GPU index.
A large NQ search is like this:
NQ = 10000
target_vectors = []
for i in range(NQ):
  target_vectors.append(random_vector)

results = collection.search(
            data=target_vectors,
            anns_field="xxx",
            param=search_params,
            limit=topk,
            consistency_level="Eventually",
        )

You can try increasing the "Concurrency", or higher NQ value for each request.
NQ = 100
vectors_to_search = [np.random.rand(1536).tolist() for _ in range (NQ)]

In my opinion, to get higher QPS, you'd better generate the random vectors outside the loop. You can pre-crate a list of random vectors before the threads start. Then pick random vectors from the list inside the loop.
